# Expand column of tuples with names from column of lists in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column of tuples `values` and a column of lists `cols`:

```py
   id          values                   cols
0  62        (alpha,)                [class]
1  22      (alpha, x)         [class, style]
2  98      (beta, no)         [class, drama]
3  15  (gaga, y, yes)  [class, style, drama]
4  73            (x,)                [style]
5  39     (y, oh yes)         [style, drama]
6  76          (hey,)                  [wut]
```

I need to expand the `values` so the output keeps the same length as the original DataFrame, but having the new column names follow what is seen in the `cols` column:

```py
   id  class style   drama  wut
0  62  alpha   NaN     NaN  NaN
1  22  alpha     x     NaN  NaN
2  98   beta   NaN      no  NaN
3  15   gaga     y     yes  NaN
4  73    NaN     x     NaN  NaN
5  39    NaN     y  oh yes  NaN
6  76    NaN   NaN     NaN  hey
```

Is it achievable without resorting to `iterrows`?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way, though it's not very pythonic, if anyone is able to improve upon it, be my guest:

```py
# Apply a DataFrame.from_records on each row
ll = list(
    df.apply(lambda r:
                pd.DataFrame.from_records([r['values']], columns=r['cols'],
                                          index=[r.name]), axis=1))
ndf = pd.concat(ll)
merged = df.join(ndf).drop(columns=['values', 'cols'])
```